# Who were the Hermotybians and Calascirians mentioned as making up the warrior caste of Egypt by Herodotus

Tags: identification, ancient-egypt

I was reading this [wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Medjay) article about an elite military force in Egypt which began as an ethnic tribe from the deserts of the eastern Sudan. This tribe was called Medjay. It was mentioned  that some of the Medjay had Egyptian names and were depicted as such in wall paintings. Egyptologists say that this was due to the influx of ethnic Egyptians into this group.

While researching on this, I encountered something curious in page 164 of Herodotus' Histories book II.

> [164]  The  Egyptians  are  divided  into  seven  distinct  classes  - 
>   these are,  the  **priests**,  the  **warriors**,  the  **cowherds**,  the 
>   **swineherds**,  the **tradesmen**,  the  **interpreters**,  and  the  **boatmen**. 
>   Their  titles  indicate their  occupations.  The  warriors  consist 
>   of  **Hermotybians**  and **Calascirians**,  who  come  from  different 
>   **cantons**,  the  whole  of  Egypt being  parcelled  out  into  districts
>   bearing  this  name.

He also expanded on the warrior caste in page 168

> [168] The  warrior  class  in  Egypt  had  certain  **special  privileges**  in
>   which  none  of  the  rest  of  the  Egyptians  participated,  except 
>   the priests.  In  the  first  place  each  man  had  twelve  arurae 
>   of  land assigned  him  free  from  tax.  (The  arura  is  a  square 
>   of  a  hundred Egyptian  cubits,  the  Egyptian  cubit  being  of  the
>   same  length  as  the Samian.)  **All  the  warriors enjoyed  this 
>   privilege  together**,  but  there were  other  advantages  which  came 
>   to  each  in  rotation,  the  same man  never  obtaining  them  twice.
>   A  thousand  **Calascirians**,  and  the same  number  of  **Hermotybians**, 
>   formed  in  alternate  years  the  **bodyguard  of  the  king**;  and 
>   during  their  year  of  service  these  persons, besides  their 
>   arurae,  received  a  daily  portion  of  meat  and  drink, consisting
>   of  five  pounds  of  baked  bread,  two  pounds  of  beef,  and four 
>   cups  of  wine.

He described them as Hermotybians and Calascirians. What are the meanings of these names in the greek language?

Are these groups the same as the Medjay?

As for the Medjay, I want to know if it has become possible for archeologists to locate their modern descendants.

Comment: The last mention of the Medjay is during the Twentieth Dynasty (1189–1077 BCE). As the Wikipedia article notes, "_It is unknown whether the Medjay as an occupation had been abolished or the name of the force had changed_".   Herodotus wasn't even born until 485 BCE, 6 centuries after the Medjay were last mentioned in the records of Ancient Egypt.

Comment: @sempaiscuba Does this mean that Herodotus is not a credible source. Most archeologists today are writing about histories that predated their birth by thousands of years. Personally, i have long been Helleno-centric in my study of Egyptology. Since the Greeks ruled over Egypt and got lots of intellectual stimulation from the Egyptians, I tend to accept the Greeks as the final authority in all questions pertaining to the Egyptians. The problem I'm having here is some of the names that they used to describe groups in the country.

Comment: Herodotus simply states that the Hermotybians and Calascirians were recruited from two different groups of Egyptian Nomes. He does not claim that the Medjay are related in any way to them. As for the credibility of Herodotus, most historians doubt whether he ever actually visited Egypt given the errors and omissions in his works.

Comment: To give two specific examples though, Herodotus gave a detailed description of the Pyramids of the Giza plateau, and omitted the Sphinx - probably not something he would have done had he actually visited the site!  Also, his descriptions of Egyptian embalming (and those of Diodorus Siculus for that matter), are [now known to be wrong](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0018442X12001278), or to quote from that article '***The Herodotean and Diodorean stereotypes, ... are falsified by the data***'.

Answer (score 7):

The Hermotybians and Calascirians mentioned by Heordotus appear to be simply two parts of the Egyptian army, each recruited from particular parts of the country.  Indeed, Hordotus himself makes this explicit:

> "Their warriors are called Calasiries or Hermotybies and they are of the following districts, for all Egypt is divided into districts.
>
> The following are the districts of the Hermotybies:Busiris, Sais, Chemmis, Papremis, the island called Prosopitis, and the half of Natho. From these districts are the Hermotybies, being in number, when they are most numerous, a hundred and sixty thousand. None of these learn any mechanical art, but apply themselves wholly to military affairs.
>
> These next are the districts of the Calasiries: Thebes, Bubastis, Aphthis, Tanis, Mendes, Sebennytus, Athribis, Pharbaethus, Thmuis, Onuphis, Anysis, and Myecphoris; this district is situated in an island opposite the city of Bubastis. These are the districts of the Calasiries, being in number, when they are most numerous, two hundred and fifty thousand men ..."

- Herodotus [Histories Book II](https://archive.org/details/historiesofherod00hero/page/146)

This division of the army into two parts was not something introduced by the Greeks, but is also attested in much earlier records.

For example, the *Great Edict of Horemheb* states that:

> The two divisions of troops which are in the field, one in the southern region, the other in the northern region, stole hides in the whole land, not passing a year, without applying the brand [?] of the royal house to cattle which were not due to them, thereby increasing their number, and stealing that which was stamped from them. They went out from house to house, beating and plundering without leaving a hide for the people.

- Quoted in Breasted, [Ancient Records of Egypt, Volume II](https://archive.org/details/ancientrecordse09breagoog/page/n58)

This division of the armies is hardly unsurprising, given the geography of Egypt. Dividing their forces into a northern and a southern contingent enabled Egypt to guard against any threat from Kushites to the south and also from whoever was the dominant Mesopotamian power of the day in the north.

---

These is some difficulty with the [Nomes](https://www.ancientegyptonline.co.uk/nomes.html) (or '*districts*' or '*cantons*' depending on one's preferences) listed by Herodotus, since many of the 42 Egyptian Nomes are not mentioned:

[image: Egyptian Nomes]

- Image source [Wikimedia](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Ancient_Egypt_map-hiero.svg)

It is possible that some Nomes were exempted from providing troops or, perhaps more likely, that Herodotus was unfamiliar with the system of Nomes - having probably never actually visited Egypt - and so only listed the ones that he was aware of.

---

As for the Medjay, the last mention of the Medjay is during the Twentieth Dynasty (1189–1077 BCE). As the Wikipedia article you cited notes,

> "*It is unknown whether the Medjay as an occupation had been abolished or the name of the force had changed*".

Herodotus makes no suggestion that the Medjay were in any way related to the *Hermotybians* and *Calascirians* (or *Calasiries* and *Hermotybies*, depending on the translation of '*Histories*' you have available).  This is hardly surprising, since Herodotus  wasn't even born until 485 BCE, fully six centuries after the Medjay were last mentioned in the actual records of Ancient Egypt.

Comment: As usual this is a solid answer. I was curious about the Medjay because as Elite warriors they too would have been part of the second most important caste in Egyptian society(except the caste groups were something Herodotus made up by himself). Since Herodotus mentioned the two groups as Hermotybians and Calascirians, then it is tempting to make a connection between these groups of warriors and the Elite force of Pharaohs army. Even if the Medjay were no longer mentioned after the 20th dynasty, their fame in the historical battles of the surrounding regions should have earned them a mention.